# .csv prep in python Anaconda for concetenate, a partial success

Tags: python, pandas

I have successfully concatenated part of my data but need some pointers in dtype prep to concatenate the entire dataset, I think!

9 csv's (same column headers) to concatenate in python Anaconda. First, 6 no prob (df1-6). 7-9 (df7-9) not happening (.csv's are no > 5mb). I tried defining the dtypes based on the dtypes it guessed for .csv's 1-6, with some tweaking but it does not recognize Float64 as a dtype in my code, also tried low_memory=False, it did not know what False was. Newbie.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('AN.csv', header=0, nrows=1934)
df2 = pd.read_csv('J.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=89656)
# df2.head displayed minor data issue,  this files timestamp is missing seconds so need to auto add :00 somehow after remedy greater issue"
df3 = pd.read_csv('SN.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=6129)
df4 = pd.read_csv('SR.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=975)
df5 = pd.read_csv('UP.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=3080)
df6 = pd.read_csv('YS.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=168)
#df7 = pd.read_csv('FL.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=408, low_memory=False)
df7 = pd.read_csv('FL.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=408,
                  df7.dtype={"Date and Time (UTC)": object,
                             "Receiver": object, "Transmitter": object, 
                             "Transmitter Name": float64,
                             "Transmitter Serial": float64,
                             "Sensor Value": int,
                             "Sensor Unit": object,
                             "Station Name": object,
                             "Latitude": float64,
                             "Longitude": float64})
#df8 = pd.read_csv('GR.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=4698, low_memory=False)
df8 = pd.read_csv('GR.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=4698,
                  df8.dtype=({"Date and Time (UTC)": object,
                             "Receiver": object, "Transmitter": object,
                             "Transmitter Name": float64,
                             "Transmitter Serial": float64,
                             "Sensor Value": int,
                             "Sensor Unit": object,
                             "Station Name": object,
                             "Latitude": float64,
                             "Longitude": float64})
df9 = 'PL.csv'
#df9 = pd.read_csv ('PL.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=19385, low_memory=False)
df9 = pd.read_csv ('PL.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=19385,
                    df9.dtype={"Date and Time (UTC)": object,
                             "Receiver": object,
                             "Transmitter": object,
                             "Transmitter Name": float64,
                             "Transmitter Serial": float64,
                             "Sensor Value": int,
                             "Sensor Unit": object,
                             "Station Name": object,
                             "Latitude": float64,
                             "Longitude": float64})
```

When I check `dtypes` for `df1` through `df6`, they populate and are identical. When I check `df7` through `df9` it returns the error that for `df7` `'str'` object has no attribute and that `df8` and `df9` have a `NameError` and that they are not defined.

`df7.head()` returns

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'
```

while `df1` through `df6` shows me a proper data table sample.

Comment: Fair enough that you've tried to be succinct but I can't actually discern the question from this sorry.

Comment: Python could not  auto identify the dtypes of a few of my csv's I am concatenating. I tried 2 fixes that failed: manually adding dtypes (though the float64 does not show up as an option) and low_memory=False

Comment: I doubt that df7.dtype is a valid keyword argument for read_csv.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For pandas questions that usually includes sample datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few different things going on.

For the dtypes issue, in the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation there are a few examples about specifying types. You'll want to use `dtype` as the argument name, not what you have (i.e. `df7.dtypes`).

For the attribute error, it's because you're assigning a string to that variable. Namely,

```
df9 = 'PL.csv'
```

means that df9 is now a string. Try printing it and you'll see that `df9` prints `PL.csv`.

The `NoneType` errors are because Python never got to df8 and df9. (`NoneType` generally means that something went wrong and the variable doesn't exist yet.)

Comment: Roger, I deleted all the variable = string lines. RCA was right I should have added a sample of the accurately read data. Still DF1 through DF6 read and concatenates fine. Weird how the default dtypes for files 1 through 6 are all object or float64 and if I try and define them for file 7 to 9, it doesn't identify it float64. My file csv file format and headers are identical. My latest attempt looks like this df7 = pd.read_csv ('FL.csv', skiprows=0, nrows=408, dtype={"Date and Time (UTC) ":,.........."Latitude": float64, "Longitude": float64}) . I think as a rookie I need to read more.